# Call a Model that has no controller from another file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have something defined as a app >model > something.rb

```
class  Something < ActiveRecord::Base   
end
```

Now I want to call this from somewhere else. 
I read that w/o rails running, there is an ActiveRecord error(calling ActiveRecord as some unnamed variable);

How can I call , say

```
Something.create (x => y) from a helper file?
```

Comment: You can just launch `rails console`. Or run your script with `rails runner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice [blogpost](http://blog.flatironschool.com/post/58164473975/connecting-ruby-active-record-without-rails) which gives you the rundown on how to connect to ActiveRecord without rails.

In a nutshell, you need to `require` your AR files, and then call `establish_connection` with the correct configuration:

> Active record works just fine and dandy without rails, but it needs
>   things to be just so. To start, get the gem and add it to your
>   gemfile. Next, make all of your classes inherit from AR like so:
>
> [image: image1]
>
> Then you need to require it in the right places. Initially I was
>   requiring AR from the file containing each class, but this was messy
>   and confusing. So instead I moved to a solution that I’d seen Avi put
>   into the CLI playlister project, which helped clean things up: I made
>   a separate file for the entire environment called environment.rb, and
>   made it do all of the requiring for my min-app. The environment file
>   requires AR, points AR to the database file to use, and then requires
>   each of the models. Then the classes don’t have to require anything.
>
> [image: image2]